# genetic algorithm for class schedule composition

Tags: algorithm, optimization, genetic

I'm writing an application for automatic university schedule composition and using for this genetic algorithm. But now I faced some problems with realization.

At the very begining I assumed that we have classes with duration of 1 time slot (time slot = 1 hour) and we can simply put it in array (represents schedule grid: 1-d array with capacity of numberOfRooms*numberOfDays*numberOfTimeslots) and can perform mutation and crossover as well with no problems.

But know I want to improve the application and allow having classes with duration of several time slots. Here comes a lot of problems:

How can we put one class object in an array and fill all the slots (several array cells) which class must occupy (one object - several cells)?
And in compliance with how we will put it in the array, how mutation and crossover operation can be performed?
Thanks in advance! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good rule could be crossing over only classes that have equal time slots. For example, you can cross over a class that takes two time slots with two classes that take one time slot.

To represent classes having duration of many time slots, the simplest but tricky way is having a flag that for each time slot will tell you if the time slot is occupied by a new class or just a continuation of a class that started before. When you cross over you will watch that flag to make sure you are not crossing parts of classes.

Another (better) way is creating a more complex data structure: `DailyRoomOccupation`. This data structure will contain:

- the daily capacity of the room, expressed in number of time slots;
- a (double linked) list of classes scheduled for that day in that room;
- a function that calculates if the classes in the list will fit into the time slots;
- a function that permits to cross-over two different `DailyRoomOccupation`s, taking care of crossing over only equal quantities of time slots.

Comment: hm, not sure that crossing over only classes with equal duration is a good idea, cause not both of the parent can have class with such a duration in the region we going to cross over.
So in idea with DailyRoomOccupation structure you suggest to store List(with size of number of rooms) filled with the DailyRoomOccupation objects, which in turn have classes scheduled for the room, right? And could you please explain how we can then perform crossover and mutation if

Comment: ...continuation
if we will perform these operators to DailyRoomOccupation then we won't be able to rearrange classes inside an object using these operators, if we perform operators to classes in DailyRoomOccupation, then we face the problem I described at реу very beginning(